# How to retrieve the api server URL with kubeadm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a `kubectl` command which returns the API server URL?

What I want is the code I need to put instead of below `...` :

```
API_SERVER_URL=$(kubectl ...)
echo $API_SERVER_URL
http://<API_SERVER_IP>:<API_SERVER_PORT>
```

`API_SERVER_IP` should be the very same that the one in my `.kube/config`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
kubectl proxy --port=8090 &
curl http://localhost:8090/api/
```

This returns something like this:

```
{
  "kind": "APIVersions",
  "versions": [
    "v1"
  ],
  "serverAddressByClientCIDRs": [
    {
      "clientCIDR": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "serverAddress": "10.165.39.165:16443"
    }
  ]
}
```

Without proxying you can use:

```
https://10.165.39.165:16443/api
```

but you need to pass authorization in the request.

In the response you see the array with the versions.

From here you can call and inspect the versions or get what is available on that version.

```
curl http://localhost:8090/api/v1

{
  "kind": "APIResourceList",
  "groupVersion": "v1",
  "resources": [
    ....
      "shortNames": [
        "cs"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "configmaps",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": true,
      "kind": "ConfigMap",
      "verbs": [
        "create",
        "delete",
        "deletecollection",
        "get",
        "list",
        "patch",
        "update",
        "watch"
      ],
      "shortNames": [
        "cm"
      ],
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works fine:

```bash
PROTOCOL=$(kubectl get endpoints -n default kubernetes -o yaml -o=jsonpath="{.subsets[0].ports[0].name}")
IP=$(kubectl get endpoints -n default kubernetes -o yaml -o=jsonpath="{.subsets[0].addresses[0].ip}")
PORT=$(kubectl get endpoints -n default kubernetes -o yaml -o=jsonpath="{.subsets[0].ports[0].port}")
API_SERVER_URL="${PROTOCOL}://${IP}:${PORT}"
```

and its result is something like that:

```bash
echo $API_SERVER_URL
https://172.18.0.3:6443
```